# Displaying every Monday within the year in Datagridview?

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview

I'm creating a diary application using c#. I've got a datagridview, and I want to display every Monday for a year starting from the current week. Below is the code i have so far:

```
//Loop which goes through every Monday 50 times, therefore it displays every Monday for a year on the users profile.

int x = 0;

do
{
    x = x + 1;                
    string monday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + (int)DayOfWeek.Monday).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    metroDataGrid1.Rows.Add(monday);

}
while (x < 50);


//After 50 weeks have been displayed it will reset the count to 0.
if(x == 50)
{
   x = 0;
}

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in metroDataGrid1.Rows)
{
    row.Height = 60;
}
```

I've only just started learning c#, hence why this is probably miles off...

Currently it displays the current Monday week 50 times in the DGV. See below:

[Datagridview display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYv6I.png)

I need this to display every Monday for the next year in the format dd/MM/yyyy. E.g
18/11/2019
25/11/2019
02/12/2019
09/12/2019
16/12/2019
...

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're not using `x` in your calculation of next week's monday - that's where you should start.

Comment: Understand what you're doing:

`(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek` //Will return 2(Tuesday, today) 
`(int)DayOfWeek.Monday)`  //Will always return 1(Monday)

and according to your code

`string monday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + (int)DayOfWeek.Monday).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");`  // (-2 + 1) So same result each and every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're starting with DateTime.Today for each step. Instead of that you could do something alike but with code to find monday instead of using Today.

```
var currentMonday = DateTime.Today;
do
{
 monday = currentMonday.ToString();
 currentMonday = currentMonday.AddDays(7);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Managed to sort the problem out with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, if you want to format a date you can use the toString with the corresponding parameters. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

If you need all mondays of a year, you could try this approach:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var monday = FirstMondayOfYear(2019);
        var lastDay = new DateTime(2019, 12, 31);

        for (var currentMonday = monday; currentMonday.CompareTo(lastDay) <= 0; currentMonday = currentMonday.AddDays(7))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(currentMonday.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            //Add it to your list or whatever
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static DateTime FirstMondayOfYear(int year)
    {
        var tmp = new DateTime(year - 1, 12, 30);
        return tmp.AddDays(8-(int)tmp.DayOfWeek);
    }
```

Please not that I've used a for-loop instead of do while (I prefer it that way as it is pretty clear:
- Input (start Monday)
- Check (is current Monday still in that year)
- Increment (add 7 days to current monday)

CompareTo compares the current Monday with the lastDate (set it to the max-date you want to get the 'monday' for). CompareTo will return -1 if currentMonday is before lastDay, 0 if they're equal and 1 if currentMonday is later than lastDay